# What to do when one route "blocks" another?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, sails.js

I'm using nodejs (with sailsjs), and I'm having an issue with routing, here is the case:

- I have one route that handles the url `'/user/?variable'`. It links to
  a controller action that shows a profile, depending on the variable
  given; if no user is found, it returns a **404 error**.
- I have a second route that handles `'/user/find'`. It is linked to a
  controller action meant for an AJAX request that returns the user's
  id given the variables passed to it.

However, when I call `'/user/find/'` with the AJAX request, then I get the **404 error**; I guess this is because it still links to the "show profile" action, and the action can't find an user named "find".

Is this conflict common among frameworks? Are there ways to solve this? I've tried switching the order in which I declare the routes, but the response is the same. I guess it would probably cause conflict too if an user signs up with username 'find', in that case, how would I handle it? Or should I just use a completely different route?

I like `/user/find` because the name is very straightforward, though.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a really dirty way of doing it, but inside of the '/user/?variable' route, you can use an if statement to check if ?variable == 'find' and then branch off the route from there.  It's a convenient solution, but it becomes a nightmare to maintain later.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that would get clunky fast, especially if I add other methods to /user/. Hmm, so all in all, would you recommend I just leave that route exclusively for that case? I wonder how facebook does it though, they have domain/username and domain/tool urls, as far as I can see.

Comment: Right now I'm checking the web to see if there's a way to give '/user/find' priority.  Ideally, in the worst case scenario, they should be checked in the order that they're registered, so I have no clue why there was no change when you switched their order.

Comment: Yes, there should be route ordering:  http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html 

look under "route ordering".  Are you sure that the /user/find/ page exists?

Comment: Whoa, that actually works. It was a mistake of mine, because I guess I didn't save the ordering change the first time I did it, before relaunching the framework, and I thought it had no effect. I did that again, and it works great. Thank you! I still have figure out what to do in case an user is named "find", though, but I'll think about what's best. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your routes in your `app.js` or whatever file you file order matters.

```
app.get("/user/find", function (request, response) {
    //do something
});

app.get("/user/:variable", function (request, response) {
    //do something
});
```

In the above example `/user/find` takes precedence over `/user/:variable` because it is declared first.  If you need to do this I would suggest playing with the order of the declarations.  If you switch it to the following it should work.

```
app.get("/user/:variable", function (request, response) {
    //do something
});

app.get("/user/find", function (request, response) {
    //do something
});
```